# How to pass values from StepContext to Promptvalidatorcontext in bot waterfall dialog model?

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm new to Bot Framework, if i made any mistake, how to correct it?

A simple scenario of my Bot which is used for flight booking, bot gets input from user for from city, to city, departure date, return date. After receiving return date, i have to validate whether the given date is greater than departure date.

How to pass values from StepContext to Promptvalidatorcontext?

```
public class Travel_FlightBookingDialog : ComponentDialog
{

    public Travel_FlightBookingDialog(string dialogId) : base(nameof(Travel_FlightBookingDialog))
    {
        AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt(nameof(ChoicePrompt)));
        AddDialog(new ConfirmPrompt("confirmPrompt"));
        AddDialog(new TextPrompt("FROMCITY", FromCityValidationAsync));
        AddDialog(new TextPrompt("DEPARTUREDATE", DepartureValidationAsync));
        AddDialog(new TextPrompt("ARRIVALDATE", ArrivalValidationAsync));
        AddDialog(new TextPrompt("PAXCOUNT", PaxCountValidationAsync));
        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), new WaterfallStep[]
        {
            BOOKINGTYPE,
            FROMCITY,
            TOCITY,
            DEPARTUREDATE,
            ARRIVALDATE,
            PAXCOUNT,
            CLASSOFBOOKING,
            DIRECTORCONN,
            LCCORFSC,
            CONFIRM,
            FINAL
        }));

        InitialDialogId = nameof(WaterfallDialog);
    }


    private async Task<bool> DepartureValidationAsync(PromptValidatorContext<string> promptContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var DepartureDate = promptContext.Recognized.Value;
        string valifinfo = ValidateDate(DepartureDate);
        if (valifinfo == "")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            await promptContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(valifinfo);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private async Task<bool> ArrivalValidationAsync(PromptValidatorContext<string> promptContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        **//HOW DO WE GET THE VALUE OF DEPARTURE DATE HERE BECAUSE
          //HERE NEED TO VALIDATE -  RETURN DATE SHOULD BE GREATER THAN DEPARTURE DATE**
    }

    private async Task<bool> FromCityValidationAsync(PromptValidatorContext<string> promptContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var FromcityValidation = promptContext.Recognized.Value;
        var count = Convert.ToString(promptContext.Recognized.Value).Length;
        List<string> range;


        if (count != 3)
        {

            range = IataHelper1.findAirport("", FromcityValidation);
            var strlist = "";
            foreach (string item in range)
            {
                if (item != "NODATA")
                {
                    strlist += item + Environment.NewLine;
                }

            }
            if (range.Count > 0)
            {
                if (range.Count == 1)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else if (range.Count > 1)
                {

                    await promptContext.Context.SendActivityAsync($"Kindly Choose any one Airport  from suggestion List :{Environment.NewLine} {strlist}");
                    return false;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                await promptContext.Context.SendActivityAsync("Please Enter valid City name.....!!!!!");
                return false;
            }

        }
        else
        {

            range = IataHelper1.findAirport(FromcityValidation, "");
            if (range != null)
            {
                foreach (string item in range)
                {
                    if (item != "NODATA")
                    {
                        ///return Task.FromResult(true);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await promptContext.Context.SendActivityAsync("Please Enter valid City Code.....!!!!!");
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> BOOKINGTYPE(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var pmoptions = new PromptOptions
        {
            Prompt = MessageFactory.Text($"Please Choose Booking Type :"),
            Choices = GetBookingType()
        };

        return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(ChoicePrompt), pmoptions, cancellationToken);
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> FROMCITY(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        stepContext.Values["BOOKINGTYPE"] = stepContext.Result;
        var promptFromCity = stepContext.PromptAsync("FROMCITY", new PromptOptions()
        {
            Prompt = MessageFactory.Text($"Please enter Departure City Code or City Name (Eg: DEL or Delhi)"),
            RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please enter the valid City Code or City Name.....")
        }, cancellationToken);

        return await promptFromCity;
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> TOCITY(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        stepContext.Values["FROMCITY"] = stepContext.Result;
        var promptToCity = stepContext.PromptAsync("FROMCITY", new PromptOptions()
        {
            Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please enter Arrival City Code or City Name (Eg: MAA or Chennai)"),
            RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please enter the valid City Code or City Name.....")
        }, cancellationToken);

        return await promptToCity;
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> DEPARTUREDATE(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        stepContext.Values["TOCITY"] = stepContext.Result;
        var promptDepartureDate = stepContext.PromptAsync("DEPARTUREDATE", new PromptOptions()
        {
            Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please enter Departure Date : (Eg: DD-MM-YYYY format)..."),
            RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please enter the valid Date.....")
        }, cancellationToken);

        return await promptDepartureDate;
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> ARRIVALDATE(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        stepContext.Values["DEPARTUREDATE"] = stepContext.Result;
        var bookingtype = (FoundChoice)stepContext.Values["BOOKINGTYPE"];


        if (bookingtype.Value == "ONEWAY")
        {
            return await stepContext.NextAsync(null, cancellationToken);
        }

        var promptArrivalDate = stepContext.PromptAsync("ARRIVALDATE", new PromptOptions()
        {
            Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please enter Arrival Date in case of Roundtrip : (Eg: DD-MM-YYYY format)..."),
            RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please enter the valid Date.....")
        }, cancellationToken);

        return await promptArrivalDate;
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> PAXCOUNT(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        stepContext.Values["ARRIVALDATE"] = stepContext.Result;

        var promptPaxCount = stepContext.PromptAsync("PAXCOUNT", new PromptOptions()
        {
            Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please enter No.Of Passengers : (Eg: AdultCount,ChildCount,InfantCount)..."),

        }, cancellationToken);

        return await promptPaxCount;
    }


    public string ValidateDate(string Date)
    {
        DateTime dateTimeObj = DateTime.ParseExact(Date, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        if (Date != "" && dateTimeObj < DateTime.Today)
        {
            return "Date should be Future or equal To Today Date";
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for [PromptValidatorContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.promptvalidatorcontext-1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use turnContext to pass information from stepContext to promptContext.
promptContext.context.turnState. =