# Pass data from StepContext (Waterfall Step) to PromptContext (Validator)

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

I am new to bot framework. I have developed a functional MS Team bot. In one of the scenario, I have to run validations based on user input. Unfortunately I am not able to pass this User input from stepContext to PromptContext. The scenario is exact same as described in below post but the answer to this post is not working for me.

[How to pass values from StepContext to Promptvalidatorcontext in bot waterfall dialog model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64623169/how-to-pass-values-from-stepcontext-to-promptvalidatorcontext-in-bot-waterfall-d)

Just writing the crux of the issue,

I am doing this:

Step Context -

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> OneStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    stepContext.Context.TurnState.Add("L", HRProfile.Code);
}
```

}

Prompt Validator -

```
private async Task<bool> ValidateInput(PromptValidatorContext<string> promptContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 {
    var hrCode = Convert.ToString(promptContext.Context.TurnState["L"]); //Error is getting generated here
    return await Task.FromResult(promptContext.Recognized.Succeeded);

 }
```

in the above line I am getting the error as **The given key 'L' was not present in the dictionary.**

How do I achieve passing data from StepContext to PromptContext?

Comment: Are you able to log value of TurnState to console after you attempt to set it in your step and before you attempt to access it in the validator?